# Two cables in a wall segment , I need to relocate the wall toward the back and they are too short (no slack) what is the recommended way to do this?

Tags: electrical, wiring

So here is a diagram of what I am dealing with

[image]
The blue cable is used to connect the right side power plug to the left side power plug
The left side is upstream to say so.
There is no slack and no way to push/pull these cables
The yellow cable -I do not know what that cable is for.

I am removing the brown marked drywall and the plan is to relocate the cables in the back grey wall. I can't think of any other method other than two connection boxes and cables running between them (see the third picture)

This will is a closet that I am trying to make it deeper. The first picture is before
The second picture is now
[image]

The third picture is a possible solution
[image]]

Is there a better way to do this?
Update: I am reading about splice kits. Not sure if the are legal in Canada

Comment: If you are lucky, might just need to pull a longer cable(blue) from box to box.  Will need to find what the yellow cable is for, if nothing else to know what breaker to turn off.  There are some splice kits(?) that are allowed to be hidden inside of walls, but do not know if allowed everywhere or just certain locals.

Comment: Yes splice kits is a solution as well.Is there any way to find out what breaker is that cable on?

Comment: Would probably need a circuit breaker finder, unless you know what that cable powers, then turn off the breakers one by one till the power goes out.

Comment: It would be very easy if I knew a power plug or other load that is on that circuit Since this în in the middle of the wall it could go anywhere ...I guess I need an induction based tester

Comment: A pro tip,for those not wanting to open walls,  if you are opening walls and have attic access it is usually easier and faster when opening walls to extend circuits down the new wall and terminate daisy chains at the last receptacle as the runs will be stapled by code at the receptacle so it ends up being easier tapping in the attic or crawl space then pulling in a new cable unless you open the walls then re pull is easy.